# Magento2: How to override layout blocks

Tags: magento2, customer-account, wishlist

**I want to override**

> "wishlist_index_index.xml"

**with some changes.**

**Default layout output:**-
[image]

***Expected output:-***

[image]

Here I want to move comment div out side "product-item-info" div.

**Please let me know the magento2 best practice to achieve this.**

Answer (score 1):

You can override this file in your custom theme. Because using `wishlist_index_index.xml` that change is not possible.

> vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/templates/item/list.phtml

Here

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Wishlist/templates/item/list.phtml

Content for this file is..

```
<?php
/** @var \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Items $block */
$columns = $block->getColumns();
?>

<div class="products-grid wishlist">
    <?php if (count($block->getItems())) : ?>
    <ol class="product-items">
        <?php foreach ($block->getItems() as $item) : ?>
            <li data-row="product-item" class="product-item" id="item_<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($item->getId()) ?>">
                <div class="product-item-info" data-container="product-grid">
                    <?php foreach ($columns as $column) : ?>
                        <?php if($column->getNameInLayout() != 'customer.wishlist.item.inner'): ?>
                            <?= $column->setItem($item)->toHtml();?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
                <?php echo $block->getLayout()->getBlock('customer.wishlist.item.inner')->setItem($item)->toHtml(); ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
    <?php else : ?>
        <div class="message info empty">
            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('This Wish List has no Items')) ?></span>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>

<?php foreach ($columns as $column) : ?>
    <?= $column->getAdditionalHtml() ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Hope this will help you!